# React - change date format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, date-format

I am trying to read a CSV file.
The date in the file in a format - 'DD-MMM-YY'.
When I am trying to read this, I am getting an invalid date error.
01-Apr-20 - how do we read this in react?

Thanks
In advance!

Comment: post what you have done already

Comment: Are you using javascript date object? `new Date("01-Apr-20").toLocaleDateString()`

Comment: new Date('01-Apr-20','dd-MMM-yy')

Comment: Yeah, the date parses in Chrome, but not in Firefox. It's probably good to use a date library for this. Moment is good. I personally prefer date-fns https://date-fns.org/v2.15.0/docs/parse

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford to use an external library, you can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com).

Then, to read these dates, simply use the following line:

```js
moment('01-Apr-20', 'DD-MMM-YY')
```

which returns a moment object (basically like a Date-object), with a lot of functionality.

---

To install:

Node.js / npm: `npm install moment`, then import it using `require()` or `import moment from 'moment'`.

Vanilla javascript: Add the following script tag to your html-code: `<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>`.

Comment: I'll add a comment for anyone who wants to try out moment before installing it locally: Go to momentjs.com and open devtools console (`F12`). The `moment`-keyword is globally available there for testing.

Comment: how do we import  moment?

Comment: getting an error: moment is not defined, npm install moment -done

Comment: To install moment: If you're using node/npm, then simply do `npm install moment`, then import it using `require()` or `import moment from 'moment'`. If you're using vanilla javascript, simply add the following script tag to your html-code: 
`<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>`. Hope this helps.

PS: Remember to mark an answer as correct if it works out!

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to put that extra 2nd parameter. Only the 1st parameter date would suffice to convert it to a javascript date type object.
`new Date('01-Apr-20')`

If you need to show it in any particular format, you can use the date libraries packages e.g luxon (advantage of being less in size)

https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/formatting.html#presets

Comment: '01-Apr-20' is not a format supported by ECMA-262, so parsing is implementation dependent. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) In particular, parsing of two digit years is problematic: `new Date('01/02/90')` likely returns a date for 2 Jan 1990, not 1 Feb 2090 (which is how I would understand it). Also, `new Date('01-Apr-20')` returns an invalid date in Firefox.

Comment: Rightly said @RobG, parsing is implementation-dependent.